# Searching from State in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a search form in a different component from where I'm passing a text that user enters to my method `SearchEventUsingText()`. I want to display the matching fields from the state depending on the text that user sends, have added an  if-else block. Problem is only my else block is getting executed. Can anyone help me with this ? New to react :/ I tried using `indexof()` as of now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' import ShowAllEvents from
'./ShowAllEvents' import Search from './Search'

class EventsState extends Component {
   
       state={
       
        flag: false,
        SearchEvent : false , 
        title: "State Check",
        events : [
              {
                  EventId: '1',
                  EventName: 'New Year Party 2022',
                  Venue: 'The Social',
                  Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
              },
              {
                EventId: '2',
                EventName: 'StandUp Comedy',
                Venue: 'ShilpaRamam',
                Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
            },
            {
                EventId: '3',
                EventName: 'Live Music',
                Venue: '10 Downing Street',
                Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
            },
            {
                EventId: '4',
                EventName: 'Karakoe Night',
                Venue: 'The Rooftop lounge',
                Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
            }
        ]
        }

  
    

           SearchEventUsingText =(text) => {
    {if(!this.state.events.indexOf(text))
        console.log(text);
      else{
          console.log("Event not created/available. Looking for something else? ");  //THIS PART IS ONLY GETTING EXCEUTED :( 
      }  

    } }
    
    
    render() {
      
        return (
            
            <div class= "container">  
                <br/>
              
            
                {this.state.SearchEvent ? <Search searchEventUsingText={this.SearchEventUsingText}/>: null}
                </div>
            
             </div>
        )
    } 
} 
export default EventsState;
```

//////////////////////\\\\\\\\\

> SearchEventUsingText =(text) => {
> //var reg = "/"+text+"/";
>
> ```
> {if (this.state.events.findIndex(item => item.EventName === text || item.Venue === text) >= 0){
>     this.state.newEvents = this.state.events.filter(event=> event.EventName.includes(text));
>     this.setState({teststate: true});
> }
> ```

Comment: IndexOf works for a plain array. You might wanna use `.filter` function to filter inside the array. ```array.filter(item => item. EventName === criteria);```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of the `text` variable in the `SearchEventUsingText` function? If it's returning a string you'll need to do a filter because indexOf is expecting an object which matches one of the elements in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional seems wrong. `indexOf()` returns the index of the item in the array. Therefore if the item is found at index `1` your conditional would convert this to false and run your else block (`!1 equates to false`). You probably want to do

```
if (this.state.events.indexOf(text) >= 0)
```

EDIT:
If text is a string then you can do essentially the same with `findIndex()`

```
if (this.state.events.findIndex(item => item.EventName === text || item.Venue === text) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`events` is array of object and you want to search text on property `EventName` of the object. [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will not work in this case. You should use combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Something like below:

```
const SearchEventUsingText =(text) => {
  var filteredEvents = this.state.events.filter(event=> event.EventName.includes(text))
  if(filteredEvents.length > 0){
    // do something when event with name exist
    console.log(text);
  }
  else{
      // do something when matching event not found
      console.log("Event not created/available. Looking for something else? ");  //THIS PART IS ONLY GETTING EXCEUTED :( 
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Let's say I found a match in the array and then I want to display all the matching results in some component. Using includes() I'm able to do that but the problem is I'm having to enter the exact name. It's not working with partial names. I want to use regex here so that i can get all the matching entries displayed. Tried match, matchAll with filter, not getting the desired result.  Any idea on what method should i use along with filter here. Eg. I want to get all events with the names like "Live Music", "Live Show ", "Something Live" etc. Edited the code above.

Comment: Please refer to  the SearchEventUsingTexxt() above.